# ImageView layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Essentially I'm looking for something like scaleType="centerCrop" without the center.

I am having trouble making an `ImageView` display correctly when it's larger than the screen dimensions. I'm trying to display an `ImageView` that starts `top=0`, `left=0` and is not scaled. It's okay that the image does not fit on the screen. Right now I have it in a relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/postagram_blank_large"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried using a `wrap_content` on the `RelativeLayout` height and width. I've also played with `scaleType` as well as using a `Scrollview`. The problem with the `ScrollView` is that the image is both taller and wider than the display port (again this is meant to happen).

How can I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried a linear layout for the top level?  Minor note-  orientation does nothing on a relative layout.

Comment: @GabeSechan this did not fix the problem. And yes orientation does nothing, that was just there from when I replace an attempt at a LL.

Comment: Try forcing the image's scale type to center

Comment: @GabeSechan i don't want the image scale centered, i want the top left of the image at the top left of the screen so overflow happens at the bottom and right.

Answer (score 1):

could it be that `android:background` scales the image to the screensize? try to use `android:src` instead.

Comment: @SimonSays this works with scaleType="centerCrop" but I don't want the image centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/postagram_blank_large"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    />
```

`wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent` also works, use whatever you want